# Checking for convergence of series

Tags: sequences-and-series

To check the convergence of the series

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1\cdot2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot3}+\frac{1}{3\cdot4}+..\infty$

Attempt 1: Term $\displaystyle u_n= \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$

So the series becomes ...

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+..\infty$

This is an alternating series. So the series is said to be oscillatory or non-convergent.

Attempt 2: We have $\displaystyle u_n= \frac{1}{n^2}\frac{1}{1+1/n}$

and  $\displaystyle v_n= \frac{1}{n^2}$

Then $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{u_n}{v_n}=\lim_{n \to\infty}\frac{1}{1+1/n}=1$

Therefore, both $u_n$ and $v_n$ converge or diverge together. As $\displaystyle \sum v_n=\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, $\sum u_n$ must also converge.

Now my question is that which of this approaches is correct. The given answer says "convergent". So Attempt 2 should be correct.

But, how do I know which method to choose for solving unknown problems. Please advise.

Comment: Your reasoning in attempt 1 is wrong.  Just because the series is alternating doesn't mean it's not convergent.

Comment: Question about the same series: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433877/evaluate-series-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two attempts are correct but the first we should use telescoping series and also this third attempt using comparison is correct

$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\le \frac1{n^2}$$
and there are more attempts :-)

Comment: Actually the first attempt is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

To check the convergence:

$$n(n+1)=n^2+n\geq n^2$$
then $$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$$

and so $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
converge.

To calculate the limit,

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n+1}=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n}=1+\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=2}^N\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{N+1}=1+\frac{1}{N+1}$$

When you make tighten $N\to\infty $, you finally obtain
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1.$$